# Kafka: Error in setting up Kafka Zookeeper Cluster in Dockers using wurstmeister/zookeeper image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I am trying to setup multiple zookeeper and multiple kafka broker cluster in docker with following `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  zookeeper1:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2185:2181"
  zookeeper2:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2186:2181"
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper1
  zookeeper3:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2187:2181"
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper1
     - zookeeper2
  kafka1:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka"
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
     - "9095:9092"
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper1
     - zookeeper2
     - zookeeper3
    environment:
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka1
     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
     - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  kafka2:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka"
    hostname: kafka2
    ports:
     - "9096:9092"
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper1
     - zookeeper2
     - zookeeper3
    environment:
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka2
     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
     - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  kafka3:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka"
    hostname: kafka3
    ports:
     - "9097:9092"
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper1
     - zookeeper2
     - zookeeper3
     - kafka1
     - kafka2
    environment:
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka3
     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
     - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=check_new:3:1
     - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But zookeeper cluster does not gets 
formed. For example with command e.g. with

```
zookeeper1
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --replication-factor 1 --partitions 5 --zookeeper zookeeper1:2181
```

topic is created whereas with following commands e.g. with `zookeeper2` & `zookeeper3`

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --replication-factor 1 --partitions 5 --zookeeper zookeeper2:2181
```

OR

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --replication-factor 1 --partitions 5 --zookeeper zookeeper3:2181
```

I get error as

```
Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2018-07-31 09:17:55,326] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

what is the issue, is there anywhere I have to provide `broker_ids` in zookeeper image? so that zookeeper cluster will work correctly

Comment: `than available brokers: 0`... Are you sure Kafka didn't crash? Also, running three containers on one machine won't make Kafka faster.

Comment: I think you didn't configured the zookeepers as you did for kafka, each instance has no clue there are other zookeeper instances

Comment: @cricket_007 I have posted same question on their github page https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/issues/372, guy says that this image currently doesn't support zookeeper cluster.

Comment: Hmm. You might want to look at Confluent's all-in-one and cluster compose examples, but again, running multiple of these containers on one host isn't improving anything ; https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/master/examples